# While running upsert command on hudi table in sparksql I am gettting error in reading _hoodie_partition_path

Tags: apache-spark-sql, google-cloud-dataproc, apache-hudi

While reading  _hoodie_partition_path error I am facing java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:  "7df51087"
_hoodie_partition_path = 7df51087-9850-4060-b4c3-xxxxxx.parquet
**Overall error**
rg.apache.hudi.exception.HoodieUpsertException: Failed to upsert for commit time 20240214115154398
at org.apache.hudi.table.action.commit.BaseWriteHelper.write(BaseWriteHelper.java:74)
at org.apache.hudi.table.action.commit.SparkUpsertCommitActionExecutor.execute(SparkUpsertCommitActionExecutor.java:44)
at org.apache.hudi.table.HoodieSparkCopyOnWriteTable.upsert(HoodieSparkCopyOnWriteTable.java:114)
at org.apache.hudi.table.HoodieSparkCopyOnWriteTable.upsert(HoodieSparkCopyOnWriteTable.java:103)
at org.apache.hudi.client.SparkRDDWriteClient.upsert(SparkRDDWriteClient.java:142)
at org.apache.hudi.DataSourceUtils.doWriteOperation(DataSourceUtils.java:224)
at org.apache.hudi.HoodieSparkSqlWriter$.writeInternal(HoodieSparkSqlWriter.scala:431)
at org.apache.hudi.HoodieSparkSqlWriter$.write(HoodieSparkSqlWriter.scala:132)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hudi.command.InsertIntoHoodieTableCommand$.run(InsertIntoHoodieTableCommand.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hudi.command.InsertIntoHoodieTableCommand.run(InsertIntoHoodieTableCommand.scala:61)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:75)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:73)

Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "7df51087"
at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
at org.apache.hudi.index.bucket.BucketIdentifier.bucketIdFromFileId(BucketIdentifier.java:79)
at
at org.apache.hudi.index.bucket.HoodieSimpleBucketIndex.getLocationMapper(HoodieSimpleBucketInd

Comment: The error looks pretty clear to me?  `7df51087` isn't a number.

Comment: That's a _hoodie_partition_path = 7df51087-9850-4060-b4c3-xxxxxx.parquet.
It's not able to write the file. I am facing this error while upserting the data need solution for the same

Comment: Can you add more details about how this was triggered?

Comment: This was triggered from google dataproc cluster

Comment: upsert in hudi is not working properly for older records when it is updating it's not able to update the older data existing in table and might be trhrowing error for  _hoodie_partition_path. But when I am running same command by pointing it to new location suppose say location = ga://xx/table_tmp/ then upsert is happening properly. Facing problem when it's trying to upsert data to the older path i.e., exact table location  suppose say location = ga://xx/table/

Comment: It was error with exception for few iteration data was getting upserserted  after around 10 iteration it started failing with recursive update error when we fixed its started giving error like: Failed to upsert for commit time 20240214115154398

Comment: Version which I am using
Spark-3.3.2
Dataproc-2-1
Hudi-2.12-0.14.0